# Vanilla js- game not running

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I decided to write a simple game as JavaScript practice, and found a greater challenge than originally anticipated.  The game should operate according to these instructions:

> upon starting the game one of three words will appear at the top of the page ("red", "blue", or "yellow") - the player then has three seconds to click the button of the corresponding color - otherwise the game will end

Upon clicking the start game button, the game begins but immediately redirects to the end game page.  I believe my main problem lies with setting and clearing the timeout.

```js
    //begin the game
    function start() {
 getCommand();
 document.getElementById("start").hidden = true;
    }

    function getCommand() {
 //generate color of button player should push
 var computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
 var color;
 switch (computer) {
 case 1:
 color = "blue";
 break;
 case 2:
 color = "red";
 break;
 case 3:
 color = "yellow";
 break;
 }
 
 //generate color of text displayed to screen
 var computerB = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
 var textColor;
 switch (computerB) {
 case 1:
 textColor = "#0000ff";
 break;
 case 2:
 textColor = "#ff0000";
 break;
 case 3:
 textColor = "#ffff00";
 break;
 }
 //print instructions for player to screen
 document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = color;
 document.getElementById("display").style.color = textColor;
 countdown();
    }
 
    //begin the countdown
    function countdown(color, click) {
 var timer = setTimeout(endGame(), 5000);
 
 //stop countdown upon correct event
 if (color == click) {
 clearTimeout(timer);
 start();
 }  
 }
 
    //end the game
    function endGame() {
 window.location.href = "endGame.html";
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Buttons</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/buttons.css">
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="commands">
 <h1 id="display"></h1>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/buttons.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/animateClick.js"></script>
 </div>
 <div id="buttons">
 <img src="images/redButton.png" alt="" width="120px" id="redButton" onclick="countdown("red")" onmousedown="clickSwapRed()" onmouseup="swapBackRed()">
  <img src="images/blueButton.png" alt="" width="120px" id="blueButton" onclick="countdown("blue")" onmousedown="clickSwapBlue()" onmouseup="swapBackBlue()">
  <img src="images/yellowButton.png" alt="" width="120px" id="yellowButton" onclick="countdown("yellow")" onmousedown="clickSwapYellow()" onmouseup="swapBackYellow()">
 </div>
 <div id="bottom">
  <button id="start" onclick="start()">Start Game</button>
 </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have refactored my js many ways, but apparently not the correct way.
Please help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: first thing to do is fix your syntax errors

Comment: `startCountdown` is not defined and there is an unexpected `}`